# IQueryable.Include() method takes a long time to execute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable

I'm using EF 6.0 and have written a method like this,

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = GetQuery();
            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty).AsNoTracking();
            }
            return query;
        }
```

here `query.Include(includeProperty).AsNoTracking();` line takes a long time to execute, even there is only one include property. Can someone tell me the reason for this?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

GetQuery() method is this,

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery<TEntity>() where TEntity:class 
        {
            return this.DbContext.Set<TEntity>();
        }
```

Comment: Normally this kind of code should run in an instant. You're only building an expression tree, which should not executing any query yet. Are you sure that no queries are emitted during the loop?